# What is the preferred IUPAC name of o-toluidine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, amines

Why does o-toluidine have 2-aminomethylbenzene as its IUPAC name?

Why isn't it named as a derivative of amine (like 2-methylaniline)? Aren't amines given a higher priority than alkanes in nomenclature?

See the [Priority Chart](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/) given on Master Organic Chemistry for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, your rationale is correct.

Generally, the selection of a preferred parent structure is based on the seniority of classes, which gives priority first to characteristic groups expressed as suffixes. Since *o*-toluidine (note that this name is no longer recommended) contains only one characteristic group $(\ce{{}-NH2})$, it is named as amine.

According to Subsection P-62.2.1.1.1 of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the retained name “aniline” is the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) for the functional parent compound. The systematic name “benzenamine” may be used in general nomenclature.

[image: aniline]

For the retained name “aniline”, substitution is permitted at any position. Substitution of such functional parent compounds is limited to substituent groups having a lower seniority than that denoted by the (explicitly expressed or implied) suffix of the functional parent compound. Anyway, in this case, this limitation is not relevant since *o*-toluidine contains only one characteristic group and carbon compounds (rings or chains) have a lower seniority than amines.

Therefore, the PIN for *o*-toluidine is “2-methylaniline”. The systematic name “2-methylbenzenamine” may be used in general nomenclature.

[image: 2-methylaniline]

Comment: But why is it "[2-amino-1-methylbenzene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toluidine)" rather than "1-amino-2-methylbenzene"?

Comment: @DGS This appears to be a separate question. The name “2-amino-1-methylbenzene” is unambiguous and describes the correct structure; however, it is not in accordance with IUPAC recommendations for several reasons. Even if we ignore the higher seniority of amines and name the compound as “benzene”, the numbering would be “1-amino-2-methylbenzene” rather than “2-amino-1-methylbenzene” since both names correspond to the locant set “1,2” (all prefixes considered together in a series of increasing numerical order) and “amino” is cited first as a prefix in the name (see Subsection P-14.4, f and g).

Comment: That's what I thought. I think it fit in with his question (yes, he specifically mentions aniline in one of his questions), but maybe it should get its own question.

Comment: I don't understand your answer,can you explain more?